# Write MySQL query with out rollup

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, union, union-all

I have a problem. How can I write this sql statment without **roll up**?
I want to get the same result, but without rollup. The result should look like the image below.

my query

```sql
select state, city, sum((sales.retail_price - products.wholesale_price) * 
sales.quantity) as profit 
from products, sales
where sales.product_id = products.product_id
group by state, city WITH ROLLUP
order by state is null, city is null, state, city ;
```

my schema

```sql
-- Create some tables and insert some rows.
create table products (product_id integer, wholesale_price real);
insert into products (product_id, wholesale_price) values 
    (1, 1.00),
    (2, 2.00);

create table sales (product_id integer, retail_price real, 
    quantity integer, city varchar, state varchar);
insert into sales (product_id, retail_price, quantity, city, state) values 
    (1, 2.00,  1, 'SF', 'CA'),
    (1, 2.00,  2, 'SJ', 'CA'),
    (2, 5.00,  4, 'SF', 'CA'),
    (2, 5.00,  8, 'SJ', 'CA'),
    (2, 5.00, 16, 'Miami', 'FL'),
    (2, 5.00, 32, 'Orlando', 'FL'),
    (2, 5.00, 64, 'SJ', 'PR');
```

[image]

Comment: *I want to get the same result, but without rollup.* What is the reason? PS. Create 3 separate queries each with its own grouping then UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use an UNION operation, as follow:
The first query returns the SUM grouped by state and city, the second only for state, and the third (without group by) for all rows

```
select state, city, sum((sales.retail_price - products.wholesale_price) * 
sales.quantity) as profit 
from products, sales
where sales.product_id = products.product_id
group by state, city
UNION ALL 
select state, NULL, sum((sales.retail_price - products.wholesale_price) * 
sales.quantity) as profit 
from products, sales
where sales.product_id = products.product_id
group by state
UNION ALL
select NULL, NULL, sum((sales.retail_price - products.wholesale_price) * 
sales.quantity) as profit 
from products, sales
where sales.product_id = products.product_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, but at `ÙNION ALL` there is a syntax error `Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION ALL  select state, NULL, sum((sales.retail_price - products.wholesale_pric' at line 7 0.015 sec
`

Comment: @Test: i've fixed. I remove the order by clause. If you wasnt, you can add at the end after wrapped three queries